# Open a fragment from item click

Tags: android

Can you help me please , how I can open a different fragment on each item on the list? I have read and tried many things but can not. What I would like is

Case:0,
 Case 1: etc ......

I must say that the list does not change the order or size , are always the same items and not move around.

Thank you for your answer.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.R;
import com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.RecyclerView.RecyclerViewClasses.Calendario;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter_Calendario extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Calendario.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Calendario> calendario;
    Context context;

    private final View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(context,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public Adapter_Calendario(Context context, ArrayList<Calendario> calendario) {
        this.calendario = calendario;
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Create new views. This is invoked by the layout manager.
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final TextView textViewJornada = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_jornada);
        final TextView textViewFecha = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fecha);
        final TextView textViewHora = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_hora);
        final TextView textViewEquipo_local = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_equipo_local);
        final TextView textViewResultado_local = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_resultado_local);
        final TextView textViewResultado_visitante = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_resultado_visitante);
        final TextView textViewEquipo_visitante = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_equipo_visitante);

        final ImageView imageViewEscudo_local = (ImageView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_escudo_local);
        final ImageView imageViewEscudo_visitante = (ImageView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_escudo_visitante);


        textViewJornada.setText("Jornada: "+calendario.get(position).getJornada());
        textViewFecha.setText("  El  "+calendario.get(position).getFecha()+"     ");
        textViewHora.setText("A las  "+calendario.get(position).getHora()+"  ");
        textViewEquipo_local.setText(calendario.get(position).getEquipo_local());
        textViewResultado_local.setText("   "+calendario.get(position).getResultado_local()+"   -   ");
        textViewResultado_visitante.setText(calendario.get(position).getResultado_visitante()+"   ");
        textViewEquipo_visitante.setText(calendario.get(position).getEquipo_visitante());


        Picasso.with(context).load(calendario.get(position).getEscudo_local())
                .placeholder(holder.view.getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_icon)).into(imageViewEscudo_local);

        Picasso.with(context).load(calendario.get(position).getEscudo_visitante())
                .placeholder(holder.view.getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_icon)).into(imageViewEscudo_visitante);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return calendario.size();
    } 

    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public View view;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            view = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing, and you are not following the RecyclerView proper format?

Comment: My problem is not as open fragment.class from the listview using case 0, case 1 etc....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three ways to do this things.

1) You can implement `OnTouch` event for `RecycleView` using `gesture` and use `position` in a switch case.

2) In your adapter class make click listener for your parent layout of your xml file and same use `position` in switch case.

3)You can create a interface in your adapter class and register on click event of your parent layout and implement your activity with that interface.